# How can I solve a #REF error when updating table using an Excel setting or VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, ref

I have an excel sheet and a formula which depends on the data in a table. I have just replaced the way to refer the arguments of my function from "DATA_F!$A$2:$A$1902;$K$1" to "Tabla_F[DATA];$K$1" (I have advantages this way that I do not want to miss)
I use a macro to import a table which is updated every week with more data, so I currently erase the table before importing the new one and everything goes right, but using the reference to the table I now get a #REF error.

I thought I could solve the problem using Application.Calculation = xlManual until importing the table to avoid the function calculations refreshment and then switch to Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic but it won't solve the problem so I do not know what is going on and how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: REF error is returned always if you delete any cell involed in the formula. **Not tested** but maybe using VBA you could conver the formula to a normal text adding a single quote before it, like `'=Tabla_F[DATA];$K$1` , edit your table as you need, and then delete the `'` from the formula and maybe force recalculation

Comment: Thank you very much @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns! IT WORKS :-). It would be great though to know why it reacts that way because I see your solution analogue to switch to manual calculation and then back to automatic calculation... There must be somehting else in background...